# Codeigniter 3.1.7 is losing session when this is called through a method

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I have a method which retrieve a session created before in a method. This method is called from AJAX and is something like:

```
public function Confirmar() {
   print_r($this->session->userdata);
}
```

The session was created before from one method in the same controller which is:

```
public function Token($token) {
    $params = array('tokenvalido' => true, 'token_de_cambio' => $token, 'user_mail' => $TokenValido->user_mail);
    $this->session->set_userdata($params);
}
```

When i make a `var_dump($this->session->userdata)` in the `Token` method, I'm getting this response:

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1522819707 [tokenvalido] => 1 [token_de_cambio] => 5ac44d3e7dc5cd0d11e2edbdb34ae13f05d60c3b64978 [user_mail] => babasonicofernando@gmail.com )
```

But when I called the `Confirmar()` method (which exists in the same controller where I create the session) this is displaying an empty array.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you dont call `$param` in `Comfirmar`. have you try to use `$this->session->set_userdata($params);` ? or you can put it in construct function as a public variable in your controller.

Comment: Hi. I edited my question modifying what I'm gettin in my var_dump response

Comment: Tbh I've heard of this issue before (twice here on stack a few weeks ago - similar question) and it is *really* really hard to figure out the base cause as it isn't a pervasive issue. I would suggest trying to save your sessions in the db to see if that alleviates the issue. You could also try changing the session cookie name. I've also heard of AJAX for some reason playing a role, but that was supposedly fixed in CI 3.0. Weird question, have you tried in different browsers?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did'nt tryed yet in other browsers, but I will. So, also I will try the solution saving the sessions in a table, I hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

`userdata` is method so you have to add `()` at end in . so change your code as below

```
public function Confirmar() {
   print_r($this->session->userdata());
}
```

Comment: Hi. `$this->session->userdata` is working fine because is retrieving data

Comment: Even using `$this->session->userdata()` still not working

Comment: oddly enough the OP stumbled upon the `$userdata` property of the session class which acts as an alias for `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('token_de_cambio'))
```

Answer (score 0):

After all this time i was noticed enabling `session.auto_start` directive in php.ini the issue is solved.